# How to increment string like VH-AAA to VH-AAB?

Tags: microsoft-excel

So how do I increment a string like VH-AAA to VH-AAB?

Because I'm trying to fill out a sheet with a bunch of aircraft codes and to start off there are 178 of them and I need codes for them all but can't be bothered to write each one out.
for example:

[image: IMG:]

that is what my current stuff is. but I want to do column E automatically due to this list having almost 200 rows.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086785/how-to-increment-string-like-aa

Comment: Hi @Mamothdinolover 112 , could you please [edit] your post & share some sample data,,, basically what you are expecting after `VH-AAAZ` !!

Comment: @RajeshS I have edited it!

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio that doesn't work. I need to have "VH-" in front and have 3 letters that auto-increment each time.

Comment: @RajeshS after VH-AAZ it should go to VH-ABA

Comment: @Mamothdinolover112, I can show you VH-AAA to VH-AAZ then VH-AAAA to VH-AAAZ then VH-AABA onward,, will it works for you please confirm through comments.

Comment: @RajeshS that is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @Mamothdinolover112,, check my post may this help U ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting a formula from [Here](http://exceltipsandkeys.blogspot.com/2012/05/increment-letters-in-excel.html)

This formula will work up to VH-AZZ which covers your requirement, incrementing the next letter is a little more time consuming, it assumes VH-AAA is in A1.

```
="VH-A"&IF(RIGHT(A1,1)<>"Z",MID(A1,5,1)&CHAR(CODE(RIGHT(A1,1))+1),CHAR(CODE(MID(A1,5,1))+1)&"A")
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Thank You very much!

Comment: What does CODE do ? (great answer btw !)

Comment: @PeterH returns the char() number of the target.

Answer (score 0):

**Combination of UDF (User Define Function) & Helper data solves the issue:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- To open VB editor press `Alt+F11`.
- From **I**nsert TAB hit **M**odule.
- **C**opy & **P**aste this code.

  ```
  Function ColLtrs(i As Long) As String
  ColLtrs = Replace(Cells(1, i).Address(False, False), "1", "")
  End Function
  ```
- Press **Alt+Q** to return to sheet and **S**ave the workbook as **M**acro  enable.
- For helper data enter `A` in cell `O36`.
- Formula in cell `O37`:

`=IF(ROW(A1)<=70,ColLtrs(ROW(A2)),"")`

- *Fill it down.*
- *`<=70` generates alphabets in 70 next rows, is editable for you it should `<=178`.*
- Write `VH-AAA` in cell `P36`
- Formula in cell `P37`:

`=LEFT(P$36,5)&O37`

- *Fill it down.*
- *Here `5` is editable.*

*You may adjust increment as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

If the last three letter combinations do not exceed `XFD`, you can use the following formula starting from excel 2007 version:

```
="VH-" & SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,702+ROW(ZZ1),4),"1","")
```

[image]